automaitcally export analytics from Dialogflow
I need to get the analytics from a specific DialogFlow agent and export them to another program.
Is there a way to do this via an API?
I looked through the DialogFlow API documentation already and was unable to find a way to access the analytics.
Thanks in advance.
